# preg_match RegExp in beginning, inside or end of word

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm very new to this regular expression bit.

I've been trying these online services but at loss.

I need it explained to me how to write a pattern that match deroot, derooted, rooted and root anywhere in string when searching for 'root'

Comment: That sounds more like strpos() than regular expressions....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_match("/root/s", $input_line, $output_array);
```

you can use this to find any string that contains `root` .

demo here : http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/4v0

Answer (score 1):

Pattern is pretty simple:

```
/(root)/
```

You can add some modifiers i, g, m:

```
/(root)/i // for case-insensitive search
```

Comment: You even don't need braces, my fault, sorry